# JavaScript: convert an image blob into an array of floats

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing, blob

I'm trying to convert a grayscale PNG blob to an array of floats such that each float represents the brightness of each pixel in the PNG, similarly to how numpy handles images.

I'm currently doing that as follows:

```
var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = function(e) {
    var byteString = e.target.result;
    byteString = byteString.split(',')[1];
    var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    var floatArray = [];

    for (var i=0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        floatArray[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i)/255;
    }
fileReader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

but this ends up returning an array much smaller than the image, and filled with seemingly random floats.

I imagine I've misunderstood how the data is actually stored in the blob and so the conversion just doesn't work as it should

Comment: What is `fileReader` in `new fileReader()`? There is a `FileReader`, is it a typo, or something else?

Comment: oh yea, my bad, it was just a typo when i was transcribing

Comment: I looked at a sample png data-URL, and it had things like "\u0089PNG" in the result (likely png-file-format header stuff. edit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header, seems to be the case). Also, doesn't png support lossless compression? I am admittedly not sure, but feel like the data you are reading is not the format you expect, at all. If you get no better option, maybe print it to an off-screen `canvas`, and use [`getImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData)